# What's causing "TypeError make_toctree at ... is not JSON serializable" on Read the Docs?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

In several projects on Read the Docs (including my own), I see variations on this error message: "TypeError make_toctree at ... is not JSON serializable".

Examples are:

https://readthedocs.org/projects/hgvs/builds/3334927/
https://readthedocs.org/projects/pyhatch/builds/3270548/
https://readthedocs.org/projects/xymath/builds/3300272/

Docs build fine locally.

Any suggestions about how to debug this or suspicions about the cause?

(Also asked at https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/1676)